# JavaScript Global Array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to figure out how to use a Global Array and holding 500 in an array and holding a picture/jpg to be 20x20 in size. Basically the picture would be multiplied on the screen.

For example this is what I have right now.

```
(function(food) { 
    food.arr[500]; 
} ) (this);
```

if I need to call on a picture to multiple it randomly all the time. How would this be done?

I'm still thinking about just Java, NOT JavaScript.

Comment: "I'm still thinking about just Java, NOT JavaScript." ????????

Comment: can you share more code? what is `this` in that context?, what exactly do you mean with `Global Array`?

Comment: I think the global array terminoligy is incorrect.  I think is meant to be a self fireing function as well. But this is just a guess. Some clarification would be good op.

Comment: I believe that you are looking for `food.arr = []` - there are no array (or any type-) declarations in JS, and arrays don't have fixed sizes (`500`) but rather grow dynamically (Java: `ArrayList`).

Answer (score 0):

I dont think that you are need Global array.

Try something like this.

```
// Step 1 make array
var arrayFoo = ["someImageLink","anotherImageLink"/*,....etc etc*/];
var output = "";

// Step 2 print images to screen
for(var i = 0; i < arrayFoo.length; i++){
    output += "<img src='"+arrayFoo[i]+"'></img>"
}

// Output the code to screen what everway you want
```

Comment: Your `arrayFoo` currently *is* a Global array?

Comment: Depends on the context of the snippet, i.e. could be in a function. But if its just sitting at the top level then yes I suppose it is. I just chucked it together quickly